# Tensorflow gather columns of a matrix very slow

Tags: tensorflow, multiple-columns, tensor

Given two matrices A (1000 x 100) and B (100 x 1000), instead of directly computing their product in tensorflow, i.e., `tf.dot(A,B)`, I want to first select 10 cols (randomly) from A and 10 rows from B and then use the `tf.dot(A_s,B_s)`

Naturally, the second multiplication should be much faster as the number of required multiplications reduces by factor of 10.

However, in reality, it seems selecting given columns of matrix A in tensorflow to creat A_s is an extremly inefficient process.

Given indices of the required columns in `idx`, I tried the following solutions to creat A_s. The solutions are ranked according to their performance:

1. `.   A_s = tf.transpose(tf.gather(tf.unstack(A, axis=1), idx))`:

`tf.dot(A_s,B_s)` 5 times slower than `tf.dot(A,B)` because creating A_s is too expensive.

  2.

```
     p_shape = K.shape(params)
     p_flat = K.reshape(params, [-1])
     i_flat = K.reshape(K.reshape(
        K.arange(0, p_shape[0]) * p_shape[1], [-1, 1]) + indices, [-1])
     indices = [i_flat]
     v = K.transpose(indices)
     updates = i_flat * 0 - 1
     shape = tf.to_int32([p_shape[0] * p_shape[1]])
     scatter = tf.scatter_nd(v, updates, shape) + 1
     out_temp = tf.dynamic_partition(p_flat,
                     partitions=scatter, num_partitions=2)[0]
     A_s = tf.reshape(out_temp, [p_shape[0], -1])
```

results in 6-7 times slower product

  3.

```
      X,Y =  tf.meshgrid((tf.range(0, p_shape[0])),indices)
      idx = K.concatenate([K.expand_dims(
           K.reshape((X),[-1]),1), 
           K.expand_dims(K.reshape((Y),[-1]),1)],axis=1)
      A_s = tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(params, idx), [p_shape[0], -1])
```

10-12 times slower.

Any idea on how I can improve the efficiency of column selection process is very much appreciated.

PS1: I ran all the experiments on CPU.

PS2: Matrix A is a placeholder not a variable. In some implementation it can get problematic as its shape may not be inferred.

Comment: Have you found out a way to improve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: unfortunatly no. Meanwhile I moved to pyTorch. Strongly recommended.